# Question of Munkres article 17 problem 10

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an ordered set and it is given the order topology.How to show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

I know to show Hausdorff I have to take two points $a,b\in X$ and find disjoint open sets $U,V$ in $X$ such that $a\in U,b\in V$.Without loss of generality I can take $a<b$ .

But I cant proceed after that.Any help will be useful

Comment: What do open sets look like with the order topology?

Comment: $(a,b)$ $[a,b),(a,b]$ the last two if $X$ has smallest and largest element @graydad

Comment: Does this mean we are allowed to find an open set $W$ containing both $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $a<b$. You’ll need to distinguish two cases.

- **Case** $\mathbf{1}$: There is a $c\in X$ such that $a<c<b$. In this case you can use $c$ to produce disjoint open sets containing $a$ and $b$.
- **Case** $\mathbf{2}$: There is no such $c$. This means that $a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $X$. What can you say about the sets $(\leftarrow,b)$ and $(a,\to)$?

In case you’re not familiar with the notation, $$(\leftarrow,b)=\{x\in X:x<b\}$$ and $$(a,\to)=\{x\in X:a<x\}\;.$$

Comment: For the first one the set will be $(-\infty,b)$ if $X$ has no least element and $(l,b)$ if $l$ is least element of $X$.Is it?

Comment: And the second one gives $[b,\infty)$ if $X$ has no greatest  element ;the first set contains $a$ and second one $b$ and both are disjoint ,right sir?

Comment: @learnmore: It makes no difference whether $X$ has a least element. Are you asking about Case $2$? Yes, in that case you can use $(\leftarrow,b)$ for the open set containing $a$. You can use $[b,\to)$ for the open set containing $b$, but you have to show that it’s open; you can do this by observing that if $a$ and $b$ are adjacent, then $[b,\to)=(a,\to)$, which is certainly open.

Comment: thanks sir for your answer

Comment: @learnmore: You’re welcome.